# Strategy & Steps to whitelist Chrome cookies for Sites whose logins & passwords are saved?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, cookies, keepass, lastpass

Strategy & Steps to whitelist Chrome cookies for Sites whose logins & passwords are saved?

### Current:

- Have lots of **logins & passwords** saved in Google Chrome; fewer in opera & firefox
- **Too many cookies to go through, so need way to map between password & cookies lists** that are/ can be exported using tools & methods below:

### Tools Used for Passwords:

- Recently installed & imported a lot of the above logins & passwords:

  - Used [Nirsoft WebBrowserPassView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_browser_password.html) to export to **KeePass.csv** [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) compatible format 
    [image]
  - Used **[lastpass](https://lastpass.com/)** to import passwords into its **Password Vault**; supports **CSV export**

    - https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=1206
    - https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=143

### Tools tried for Cookies:

- Have not cleaned out all cookies for a long time, and wont do until have a final whitelist or way to whitelist existing cookies

  - Have looked at some Chrome Extensions/ Apps that do cookie management, which would also involve going through & curating all the cookies
  - Have used CCleaner to **"[keep" some cookies](https://www.piriform.com/docs/ccleaner/ccleaner-settings/choosing-which-cookies-to-keep)**, but still in process of going through all cookies and **marking ones to save - whitelist them** 
    [image]

> **Cookies to Keep:**
>
> Stored in CCleaner.ini, line 30 in field *CookiesToSave*, as concatenated list separated by |.
>
> > CookiesToSave=*.2shared.com|*.4shared.com|*.piriform.com|0.s3.envato.com|120hz.net|123rf.com...
> >     ...|youtube.com|youtube.googleapis.com|za.linkedin.com
> >
> > DefaultDetailedView=1

### Next Step advise needed:

**Critical:**

- *Need way to use/ map existing login-password list* towards **white-listing of 'existing' cookies**? Saving / protecting them and cleaning out remaining ones

**Bonus:**

- How to go about *white-listing 'future' site cookies*?

  - Apparently, [Vanilla](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vanilla-cookie-manager/gieohaicffldbmiilohhggbidhephnjj?hl=en) is an extension [that helps with this somehow](http://www.technorms.com/19629/vanilla-cookie-manager-whitelists-cookies-protect-browsing-habits) on per individual site

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is relevant to your problem.

I have written a little tool (in powershell, of all things) that applies the data in a csv file to a template.  Each record in the csv supplies actual values for an expansion of the template, with variables in the template replaced by actual values from the csv.  Using the appropriate template, you can get the output in just about any format you want, although it's stashed in a text file.

This tool might not be suitable for your purposes, but the same tool can be implemented in lots of different languages, with a little work.

---

Ok, here goes... It's probably cruddy powershell, because this is just a learning exercise for me.  But it works ok for me.  The output goes into the pipeline by default, but it's easy to redirect the output to a file.  It might be easier to follow if I added a sample csv file and template.

---

```
<#  This function is a table driven template tool. 
    It's a refinement of an earlier attempt.

    It generates output from a template and
    a driver table.  The template file contains plain
    text and embedded variables.  The driver table 
    (in a csv file) has one column for each variable, 
    and one row for each expansion to be generated.

    5/13/2015

#>

function Expand-csv {
   [CmdletBinding()]
   Param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
      [string] $driver,
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
      [string] $template
   )
   Process
   {
      $OFS = "`r`n"
      $list = Import-Csv $driver
      [string]$pattern = Get-Content $template

      foreach ($item in $list) {
         foreach ($key in $item.psobject.properties) {
            Set-variable -name $key.name -value $key.value
            }
         $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($pattern) 
         }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please do share that script{s} so I can evaluate if that approach will help.